# How to find the coordinates of a point having length l from some origin and some angle.

Tags: geometry

Let suppose i have a point $(x,y)$. I need to find a coordinate lets $(x_1,y_1)$ given that it have a distance of $l$ from $(x,y)$ and making angle $\theta$ from $x$ axis.

Comment: Are both points $\bigl(x,y\bigl)$ and $\bigl(x_1,y_1\bigl)$ on the same line, or are they making the same angle with the $x$ axis?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:algebraic-geometry]. That is a way more advanced topic. Whoever edited, please fix the tags also.

Comment: Hi prakhar the (x1,y1) and (x,y) both are on the same line and making some angle with the x axis.

Comment: Sorry for the tag, I will edit it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume at first that $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Then all possible points with distance $l$ from the origin will lie on a circumference centered at (0,0) with radius $l$, i.e., they will have the form $(l\cos(t), l\sin(t))$, where $t$ is any angle (with the $x$ axis) $t\in[0,2\pi]$. If $\theta$ is the given angle, then, the point $(x_{1},y_{1})$ would be $(l\cos(\theta),l\sin (\theta))$. For a generic point $(x,y)$ the same argument applies, but the circumference is centered at $(x,y)$ rather than $(0,0)$. A simple translation of the previous point gives the general formula $(x_{1},y_{1})= (x+l\cos(\theta),y+l\sin(\theta))$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure. ;)